# PHP font-size from HTML Form

Tags: php, html

I have a little problem. I'd like to change the text size of a link by using variable from form. I have tried using this simple process but it doesn't do anything.

Form part

```
<label name="size">Text size:</label>
    <input type="text" name="size">



if(isset($_POST['size'])) {
  $size = $_POST["size"];
}

if(isset($url)) {
  if(isset($_POST["okno"])) {
    echo "<a href='$url' title='$titul' target=_blank style='color:'$barva' font-size:'$size'>$zobrazeni</a>";
  } else {
      echo "<a href= '$url' title='$titul' style='color:$barva' font-size:'$size'>$zobrazeni</a>";
    }      
  }
```

Comment: Please show us your full form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the single quotes (`'`) around the style properties `color` and `font-size`. Those are causing a parsing error in your HTML. Also, you must have a semicolon (`;`) between the two:

```
if(isset($_POST['size'])) {
    $size = $_POST["size"];
}

if(isset($url)) {
    if(isset($_POST["okno"])) {
        echo "<a href='$url' title='$titul' target=_blank style='color:$barva; font-size:$size>$zobrazeni</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href= '$url' title='$titul' style='color:$barva; font-size:$size>$zobrazeni</a>";
    }      
}
```

Comment: The value is set but the font size is still not changing.

Comment: Have you verified that by looking at the generated HTML?

Comment: Yes. The size value is set but the link is still in basic size.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a style conflict. You haven't posted much of your HTML, and you haven't posted any of your stylesheets. But this answer fixes the problem with the HTML. So, you should probably mark this as the answer and then ask about your style problem in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following

```
if(isset($url)) {
    if(isset($_POST["okno"])) {
        echo "<a href='$url' title='$titul' target='_blank' style='color:$barva;font-size:$size;'>$zobrazeni</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href= '$url' title='$titul' style='color:$barva;font-size:$size;'>$zobrazeni</a>";
    }      
}
```